# copy user's selected items of one list to another by index

Tags: asp.net, linq, list

I have a List of strings that contains 16 strings . user selects to copy items with indexes of 0,5,6,10,15 of this list to the second List .

is there any way to do this by linq ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you already have the indices in a collection, you can use [`Enumerable.ElementAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233.aspx) which just uses the indexer for `IList<T>`, hence it's very efficient:

```
var indices = new List<int>(){ 0,5,6,10,15 };
List<String> result = indices.Select(i => strings.ElementAt(i)).ToList();
```

If you don't want to create a new list but copy them into an existing list:

```
other.AddRange(indices.Select(i => strings.ElementAt(i)));
```

Comment: thank you , what about performance ? does this approach has a better performance than a 2 nested foreach loop ?

Comment: @raza: Do you have measured it, is it too slow? Use whatever is most readable and maintainable, not what is 1 millisecond faster in 1 million iterations. Internally Linq uses loops as well, but it should not be slower since `ElementAt` uses the indexer (`strings[15]`) for `IList<T>` like lists or arrays.

Comment: @raza: Apart from that, you don't need two nested `foreach` for the _classic_ way.  `foreach(int i in indices)other.Add(strings[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = new List<string> {"sdf", "sdfsd", "fdgfdgfhg"};
var result = list.Where(x => list.IndexOf(x) == 1 || list.IndexOf(x) == 2).ToList();
```

but i do not recommend doing so, this task dot'n for linq

Answer (score 0):

Also one can use the following overload of the Where extension method:

```
var string_list = new List<string>() { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
var index_list = new List<int>() { 0, 2, 3 };
foreach (string result in string_list.Where((s, i) => index_list.Contains(i)))
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```